# Find position of left side of object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

So i want to align 2 objects together on the left side of the object that is the furthest to the left. So i'll sketch out a scenario:

There are 2 images on random positions on the board. You select both images(with a selection tool that has been made) and you than click: "Align objects to the left"
The image that is the furthest to the RIGHT should than snap to the same position of the edge on the left side of the other image. So when clicking the button, my code should calculate both left sides(the edge of the image on the left) of the images position, than check which one if the furthest to the right on the canvas, and move that one to the same X axis as the other image.

This way the end result will be the images will be on the exact same X axis. So if image 1 is on -73 & Image 2 is on -50, image 2 should than also move to -73, regardless of the rotation of either images.

Currently i can only find out how to find the middle position of the image, my code looks like this atm:

```c#
using com.company.program.core.pageObjects;
using com.company.program.ui.colorPicker;
using UnityEngine;

namespace com.company.program.core.SelectionManager
{
    public static class SelectionAlignment
    {
        public static void AlignLeft(PageObjectBase pageObject)
        {
            Debug.Log("Let's check if this is a group first!");
            if (pageObject is PageObjectGroup)
            Debug.Log("Now we can AlignLeft!");

                PageObjectGroup group = (PageObjectGroup)pageObject;
                foreach (PageObjectBase objectBase in group.Children)
                {   

                    //objectBase.transform.position

                    Debug.Log("Position is now" + objectBase.transform.position);
                    Debug.Log("Left Position is" + objectBase.transform.position + -objectBase.transform.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I have no moving function yet as im first trying to figure out what the position of the most left side of the image is. The first Debug.log works and displays the normal position(middle point of image). The second one doesn't work, and displays the same. Both images get instantiated during runtime.

Hopefully this is enough information, i'm a long time lurker but have never posted anything myself, so be gentle on me if i forgot to add information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question `left` means a smaller X value.

So in general the left edge of an image (assuming `PageObjectBase` somehow inherits from `MonoBehaviour` and you are speaking about `Image` component from Unity `UI` with a `RectTransform`)
is the most left of all four corners of the image. You can get all four corners by using [`GetWorldCorners`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html)

```
private float GetLeftEdge(PageObjectBase obj)
{

    RectTransform rectTransformComponent = obj.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

    if(!rectTransformComponent)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No Image component found", this);
        return 0;
    }

    Vector3[] v = new Vector3[4];
    rectTransformComponent.GetWorldCorners(v);

    float mostLeftCorner = float.MaxValue;
    foreach(var pos in v)
    {
         mostLeftCorner = Mathf.Min(mostLeftCorner, pos.x);
    }

    return mostLeftCorner;  
}
```

This should also work if the images are rotated.

If you are not using `RectTransform` you have to get the width another way somehow but the rest stays the same.

Than in your loop you first have to get the smallest (most left) edge so I would split it in two loops:

```
// Start with the max float value so any other value should be smaller
float mostLeftEdge = float.MaxValue;
PageObjectBase referenceToMostLeftObject;

// Get the most left position and object reference
foreach (PageObjectBase objectBase in group.Children)
{
    float leftEdge = GetLeftEdge(objectBase);

    if(leftEdge < mostLeftEdge)
    {
        referenceToMostLeftObject = objectBase;
        mostLeftEdge = leftEdge;
    }
}

// Now you have the most left edge value and the object which is your reference

// Just a little safety skip to not move to strange values

if(referenceToMostLeftObject == null || Mathf.Approximately(mostLeftEdge, float.MaxValue))
{
     Debug.LogError("Ups, I think something went wrong getting the mostLeftEdge", this);
     return;
}

// Move the other objects to match with that edge
foreach (PageObjectBase objectBase in group.Children)
{
    // Skip the reference object
    if(objectBase == referenceToMostLeftObject) continue;

    // First get the difference
    float leftEdge = GetLeftEdge(objectBase);

    // Should always be negative
    float difference = mostLeftEdge - leftEdge;

    // Than move it there
    var current = objectBase.transform.position;

    // Since difference should be negative
    // Adding it to the current position should result in the wanted position
    var newPosition = new Vector3(current.x + difference, current.y, current.z);

    objectBase.transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping me, i'm not using mono-behaviour. i'm new in my company and they have written their own behaviour as far as i know (only my first week here). I'll update my code in the post with the whole code of my script where i will replace the company's name with ~company. I have tried your first solution with no succes, but will try your second one later today when i have time. But maybe my ypdated code will point out something important that might help with your answer.

Comment: Hey I don't have two solution but both snippets together are 1 solution. And as soon as you can attach your "script" as a component to gameObjects it is somehow derived from MonoBehaviour, otherwise Unity wouldn't allow you to attach it to the objects

Comment: Bit of a late reply, but i misunderstood your answer at first, i was in a bit of a hurry. I got it working, using part of your code. Turned out they had some personal functions already made i could implement, but i used part of your code. So thanks a lot :)